# How are the two arrangements equivalent?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

An intuitive or a mathematical answer would do!

[image]

Apparently the two arrangements are equal. How is it so? I'm new to this topic and my teacher bombarded us with such a statement with no explanation and went on to the next topic.

Answer (score 1):

We know that charge on a capacitor is $q=CV$ where $V$ is the potential difference across concerned capacitor. And so accordingly in the second figure, $$q_1=C.\frac{q}{C}=q$$ And as it is a battery, potential difference remains constant so charge remains constant but do take care of the polarity of the battery. The plate of capacitor connected to higher potential is taken as $+ve$ and for the plate connected to the lower potential is $-ve.$ So it's opposite in both the figures. For the second figure, the right plate has $+q $ charge and left plate has $-q$ charge. Kindly ask in the comments if any further queries.